# How do I block Port 25 on RedHat 6.4

Tags: port, redhat-enterprise-linux

I need to block port 25 on Rehat 6.4 as Postfix smtpd is using it. I have tried to disable it in the IPtables, but if i do a port scan I can still see the port as open along with port 22 which is fine.

Comment: Have you considered disabling Postfix smtpd, then?

Comment: Red Hat Version 6.4 is End Of Life and no longer supported. You should really upgrade to a supported version. I also don't understand why you need to block a port when a service is listening on it. I assume you block all incoming ports by default and only open them when you want something to be accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

As you talk of a portscan, I suppose you mean a scan from outside your server inward. I don't know which i-tables command you did exactly use, but I would have gone down this path too, trying following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT --reject-with=icmp-host-unreachable
```

This should deny input traffic on a specific protocol and port with resulting missing route to host.